# What to do when an answer to one question is even better for another question?

Tags: discussion, answers

Consider the last answer in:
[Lockfree standard collections and tutorial or articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725827/lockfree-standard-collections-and-tutorial-or-articles/2183715#2183715).

I think it'd be the best answer for:
[non-blocking thread-safe queue in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645326/non-blocking-thread-safe-queue-in-c)

Assuming of course that SO users appreciate code reuse.

Comment: Surely it's an *indication* that the questions are duplicates.

Comment: @ChrisF: In this case one question is language-specific and the other isn't so they're not duplicates at all. Because of the language agnosticism, sstock's answer is actually pretty inappropriate for that question. :)

Comment: I did say *indication*.

Answer (score 1):

You can always create an answer to the 2nd, and [link to the other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4551/referencing-other-answers-acceptable-or-not/4552#4552).
I many times link to other SO answers that I know help the answer.

Comment: Is that best practice?

Comment: @Matt, It's best to add content, but if another answer does the job well, then providing that link is a positive.  You might just leave a message for the user to add his answer to the other question.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: I'm flagging posts which links to another question/aswer as "should be comment"

Comment: @genesis, that's too bad, and innapropriate as a general statement.  Things like this should always be done on a case-by-case basis.  Just because an answer contains a link, doesn't make it a bad answer.

Comment: I think he meant "which _just_ links", as those should be comments and often the questions should be closed as duplicates.